# C++ Windows - Trying to open files with specific applications

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying implement an open with menu. Thus I must be able to open files with specific applications. I already managed to extract the full executable paths to any given fileextension. But I cant seem to get that file opened in the executable I want.

ShellExecute seems to work in some cases if I use the executable path as lpFile and the filepath surrounded by quotation marks as lpParameters. But that doesnt seem to be the right way since some applications dont respond to that.

Any hints?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using win32 as opposed to .net?

Comment: The "verb" controls how the file will be opened. If you need to have more fine-grained control of what opening the file is, then launch the appropriate target application (not the target file) with the correct magic to specify the file to open/display - and this magic *will* differ by application. The registry verb pairing isolates most of that for registered verb/extension pairs.

Comment: If you're not using the "verb" pairing, consider [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of ShellExecute.